# Is gravel required under a concrete slab that is beneath a fence (not supporting it)?

Tags: concrete, slab, concrete-block

I have a vinyl fence around the back of my house. The posts are already supported by cement. I want to create concrete forms in between the posts to cover the dirt so I don't have to deal with weeds growing under the fence. I live in Baltimore and we have freezing temperatures in the winter.

The forms will be 5 inches wide, 4 inches deep, and range from 20 inches to 50 inches. One form will be 10 inches wide. The forms are not supporting anything and no one will be walking on them. They are purely aesthetic.

Do I need to pour gravel under these concrete forms as a base?

Comment: Do you get frost/freezing temps?   Concrete and frost heave don't get along well, without a good base.

Comment: Yes, we get frost. I've updated the question to reflect that.